# How to check that the 4th character in a file is 'a' using linux grep command

Tags: linux

To find the 2nd character it was grep -e '^.[aA]'. Then what will be for the 4th character? I tried grep -e'^...[aA]'. But it went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "it went wrong"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` processes the input line by line. `^.[aA]` is true if `a` or `A` is the second character *on any line*.

You can combine `grep` with `head` to only inspect the first line:

```
head -n1 filename | grep '^...[aA]'
```

But it still wouldn't work for a file whose first line is shorter than four characters:

```
x
ya
```

To really check the fourth character in a file, `grep` is not the best tool.

```
#! /bin/bash
read -N4 chars < filename
if [[ "${chars:3:1}" == [aA] ]] ; then
    echo Found
fi
```

But if you tried hard enough, you can still use it. E.g., use `tr` to replace newlines by spaces, then you can run your grep:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < filename | grep '^...[aA]'
```